# CV documentclass

Tags: cv, documentclass

What document class is used in [this CV](https://scholar.princeton.edu/sites/default/files/itskhoki/files/cv.pdf):

[image]

I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: Have a look here: https://www.ctan.org/topic/cv

Answer (score 3):

This should provide a sufficient start. It uses the default `article` class, with some modifications to `\section`, `\subsection` and lists using [`enumitem`](//ctan.org/pkg/enumitem):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,lastpage,graphicx,enumitem}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}% Clear header/footer
\fancyhead[L]{\normalfont\scshape Oleg Itskhoko, UCLA}
\fancyhead[R]{\sffamily Page \thepage\ of~\pageref{LastPage}}
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\renewcommand{\section}[1]{%
  \par\medskip
  \noindent
  {\normalfont\Large\scshape #1\par}
  \addvspace{\smallskipamount}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}[1]{%
  \par\medskip
  \noindent
  {\normalfont\large\scshape #1\par}
  \addvspace{\smallskipamount}}
\newlist{cvitemize}{itemize}{2}
\setlist[cvitemize]{label={},nosep}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\sffamily

\raisebox{\dimexpr-\height+.7\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{%
  \includegraphics[width=6\baselineskip]{example-image-1x1}%
}\hfill \today

\bigskip

\begin{center}
  {\Large\bfseries OLEG ITSKHOKI}
  
  \medskip
  
  \large Department of Economics \par
  \normalfont\scshape University of California, Los Angeles
\end{center}

\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{.5\linewidth} @{}}
  Bunche Hall \\
  315 Portola Plaza \\
  Los Angeles CA 90095
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} p{.5\linewidth} @{}}
  itskhoki@econ.ucla.edu \\
  www.itskhoki.com
\end{tabular}

\medskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.5\linewidth} @{}}
  Citizenship: Russia and United States
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{.5\linewidth} @{}}
  Date of Birth: January 7, 1983 in Moscow
\end{tabular}

% =================================================
\section{Academic appointments}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item University of California, Los Angeles, Department of Economics
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Venu and Ana Kotamraju Endowed Chair in Economics, July 2020--
    \item Professor of Economics, September 2019--
  \end{cvitemize}
  
  \item American Economic Review
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Associate Editor, 2019--
  \end{cvitemize}
  
  \item National Bureau of Economics Research (NBER)
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Research Associate, 2010--
  \end{cvitemize}
  
  \item Center for Economic Policy Research (CEPR)
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Research Affiliate, 2010--
  \end{cvitemize}
\end{cvitemize}

\subsection{Past appointments}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Princeton University, Department of Economics and Woodrow Wilson School, 2009--2020
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Professor of Economics and International Affairs, 2017--2020
    \item Associate Professor of Economics and International Affairs (with tenure), 2015--2017
    \item Richard Allen Lester University Preceptor, 2013--2016
    \item Assistant Professor of Economics and International Affairs, 2010--2015
    \item Associate Research Scholar, International Economics Section, 2009--2010
  \end{cvitemize}
  
  \item Alfred P.\ Sloan Research Fellow, 2015--2017
\end{cvitemize}

\subsection{Visiting appointments}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Stanford University, Department of Economics/SIEPR, Trione Visiting Professor, 2017--2018
  \item University of Chicago, Department of Economics/BFI, Visiting Professor, 2012--2013
\end{cvitemize}

% =================================================
\section{Education}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Harvard University, Ph.D.\ in Economics, 2004--2009
  \begin{cvitemize}
    \item Dissertation: International Trade and Labor Markets: Unemployment, Inequality and Redistribution
    \item Advisors: Elhanan Helpman, Gita Gopinath, Aleh Tsyvinski, Pol Antr\`as
  \end{cvitemize}
  
  \item New Economics School (Moscow), M.A.\ in Economics, 2002--2004

  \item Moscow State University, B.A. in Economics, 1999--2003
\end{cvitemize}

% =================================================
\section{Research interests}
\begin{cvitemize}
  \item Macroeconomics and International Economics
\end{cvitemize}

\clearpage

% =================================================
\section{Academic publications}
\begin{enumerate}[nosep]
  \item Oleg Itskhoki and Dmitry Mukhin (2021): ``Exchange Rate Disconnect in General Equilibrium,''
    accepted at the Journal of Political Economy. NBER Working Paper No. 23401.
  \item Cecile Gaubert and Oleg Itskhoki (2021): ``Granular Comparative Advantage,'' Journal of Political
    Economy, March 2021, 129(3), forthcoming.
  \item Mary Amiti, Oleg Itskhoki and Jozef Konings (2019): ``International Shocks, Variable Markups and
    Domestic Prices,'' Review of Economic Studies, November 2019, 86(6): 2356--2402.
  
    {\small\textsuperscript{*}Formerly circulated as ``International Shocks and Domestic Prices: How Large are Strategic Complementarities?''
    March 2016, NBER Working Paper No. 22119.}
  \item Oleg Itskhoki and Benjamin Moll (2019): ``Optimal Development Policies with Financial Frictions,''
    Econometrica, January 2019, 87(1): 139--173.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```